# String to bool (a is true rest is false)

Tags: c#, string, boolean

I was testing with c# and ran to a "little" problem. I searched the web for an hour but I found code that din't work :(

I'm testing with c# and trying to make a little quiz in the command promt

```
    //variables questions, Vraag is question, Solution is the solution, and Keuze is the three choices (a,b and c)

    string Vraag1 = ("Wat is de hoofstad van Oostenrijk?");
    string Solution1 = ("Wenen");
    string Keuze1 = ("a: Wenen b: Rome c: Kiev");
    string Vraag2 = ("Hoe heet de hoogste berg van Afrika?");
    string Solution2 = ("De Kilimanjaro");
    string Keuze2 = ("a: De Mount-everest b: De Kilimanjaro c: De Aconcagua");
    string Vraag3 = ("Wie was de uitvinder van de gloeilamp?");
    string Solution3 = ("Edison");
    string Keuze3 = ("a: Thomas Edison b: Albert Einstein c: Abraham Lincoln");

    //Other variables

        //entered1, 2 and 3 are variables that the user typed in
//code

    //Question 1
    Console.WriteLine("Vraag 1:");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(Vraag1);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Read();
    Console.WriteLine(Keuze1);
    Console.Read();
    string entered1 = Console.ReadLine();

    Boolean enteredbool1 = !entered1.Equals("a");

    if (enteredbool1)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor.Green);
        Console.WriteLine("Goedzo, op naar de volgende!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FOUT!");
    }
```

My problem is that if the user answered "a" it says its good (goedzo) but if he typed b it gives the same result not wrong (fout).

I think it has something to do with the conversion of the string to boolean. I tryd to remove the "!" but that gives reversed effects (only say's the question was wrong).

I hope someone can help!

Gijs

Comment: You have inverted the condition. If the user types 'a' then the answer is right and you should remove the ! in front of the equals. And remember that 'A' uppercase is different thant 'a' lower case for Equals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you do 'Read' twice before Readline, the value that you're verifying with Equals will always be empty (""). 
This works:

```
        string Vraag1 = ("Wat is de hoofstad van Oostenrijk?");
        string Solution1 = ("Wenen");
        string Keuze1 = ("a: Wenen b: Rome c: Kiev");
        string Vraag2 = ("Hoe heet de hoogste berg van Afrika?");
        string Solution2 = ("De Kilimanjaro");
        string Keuze2 = ("a: De Mount-everest b: De Kilimanjaro c: De Aconcagua");
        string Vraag3 = ("Wie was de uitvinder van de gloeilamp?");
        string Solution3 = ("Edison");
        string Keuze3 = ("a: Thomas Edison b: Albert Einstein c: Abraham Lincoln");

        //Other variables

        //entered1, 2 and 3 are variables that the user typed in
        //code

        //Question 1
        Console.WriteLine("Vraag 1:");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(Vraag1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(Keuze1);
        string entered1 = Console.ReadLine();

        Boolean enteredbool1 = entered1.Equals("a");

        if (enteredbool1)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor.Green);
            Console.WriteLine("Goedzo, op naar de volgende!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FOUT!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You used the negation of the correct condition, one could thus write `Boolean enteredbool1 = entered1.Equals("a");`, or shorter `bool enteredbool1 = entered1 == "a";`

To make it more robust, you can for instance `Trim()` the string, removing spaces, tabs and other noise at the front and the back of the string. `ToLower()` to convert capital letters like `A` to `a` and finally `StartsWith` to check if the string starts with the correct answer ignoring other noise (for instance `"a: Wenen"`). The final condition then becomes:

```
Boolean enteredbool1 = entered1.ToLower().Trim().StartsWith("a");
```

Furthermore some coding advice:

- use aliases, `Boolean` is equal to `bool`
- String equality in `C#` can be expressed with `strA == "a\n"`, since operator overloading is supported.
- the algorithm you propose doesn't scale well, if you want to make a quiz you will need to write code for every single question/answer.

Comment: Console.ReadLine doesn't append the newline in the returned string

Comment: You're right, but anyway, I think `StartsWith` is more robust, I've updated my answer.

Comment: The problem stated is: Any letter I type I get the same answer. It is unclear because that code (while wrong) cannot give the same answer if you type "a" or "b". Perhaps the problem lies in upper/lower case or in the mastering of the english language.

Comment: I think the topic sender only tested on `"b"` and found out that it didn't work. I think the code in the answer is correct, I've tested it with CSharpRepl and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Other option is to use startwith alongwith trim and tolower to make sure that your user's input like " a " or " A " also gets processed correctly

```
    // try to find "a" using StartsWith 
    if (entered1.Trim().ToLower().StartsWith("a")) { 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`!entered1.Equals("a")` means  its `NOT "a"`.

Since your answers are always a,b,c, etc  test just the first character. This was you can easily test for `'a'` and `'A'`

Comment: Crud, your right Steve,  "A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return (hexadecimal 0x000d), a line feed (hexadecimal 0x000a), or the value of the Environment.NewLine property. The returned string does not contain the terminating character(s)."

Comment: -removed '\n' references

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of rewrite some stuff to present another way of doing(it was done on the fly so some improvement may be in order):

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> answers = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>()
            {
                {1,new Dictionary<string,string>()
                       {
                           {"a","Wenen"},{"b","Rome"},
                           {"c","Kiev"},{"correct","a"}
                       }},
                 {2,new Dictionary<string,string>()
                       {
                           {"a","De Mount-everest"},{"b","De Kilimanjaro"},
                           {"c","De Aconcagua"},{"correct","b"}
                       }},
                  {3,new Dictionary<string,string>()
                       {
                           {"a","Thomas Edison"},{"b","Albert Einstein"},
                           {"c","Abraham Lincoln"},{"correct","a"}
                       }}
            };
            List<string> quiz = new List<string>()
            {
                "Wat is de hoofstad van Oostenrijk?",
                "Hoe heet de hoogste berg van Afrika?",
                "Wie was de uitvinder van de gloeilamp?"
            };           

            bool IsDone = false;
            int question = 1;
            while (!IsDone)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(question + "º: Vraag 1:");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(quiz[question - 1]);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("a: {0} b: {1} c: {2}", answers[question]["a"], answers[question]["b"], answers[question]["c"]));
                string entered1 = Console.ReadLine();

                if (entered1.ToLower() == answers[question]["correct"])
                {
                    ConsoleColor col = Console.ForegroundColor;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor.Green);
                    Console.WriteLine("Goedzo, op naar de volgende!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Continue playing?  [y] [n]");
                    if (Console.ReadLine() == "y")
                    {
                        question++;
                        Console.ForegroundColor = col;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                        IsDone = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FOUT!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Continue playing?  [y] [n]");
                    if (Console.ReadLine() == "y")
                    {
                        question++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                        IsDone = true;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is your Problem :  Boolean enteredbool1 = !entered1.Equals("a");

### Replace it With      :  Boolean enteredbool1 =  entered1.Equals("a");

```
        string Vraag1 = ("Wat is de hoofstad van Oostenrijk?");
        string Solution1 = ("Wenen");
        string Keuze1 = ("a: Wenen b: Rome c: Kiev");
        string Vraag2 = ("Hoe heet de hoogste berg van Afrika?");
        string Solution2 = ("De Kilimanjaro");
        string Keuze2 = ("a: De Mount-everest b: De Kilimanjaro c: De Aconcagua");
        string Vraag3 = ("Wie was de uitvinder van de gloeilamp?");
        string Solution3 = ("Edison");
        string Keuze3 = ("a: Thomas Edison b: Albert Einstein c: Abraham Lincoln");

        Console.WriteLine("Vraag 1:");
        Console.WriteLine(Vraag1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(Keuze1);
        string entered1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Boolean enteredbool1 = entered1.Equals("a");
        if (enteredbool1)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor.Green);
            Console.WriteLine("Goedzo, op naar de volgende!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FOUT!");
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check again, this is not the issue. It will return the same value for any input.